# html javascript select option control with huge number of elements (like 10K)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two  controls with huge nubmer of elements and I move elements from one to another with arrows (built as a single control).
however moving elements from one select to another takes lot of time (i have 10K elements)
i want to know if there is already a best practice or a ready made control that can do that and fast.

thanks

Comment: The first question is: Do you *need* to show all these 10k elements? I don't think a user can manage that easily anyway.

Comment: You have a User Experience problem if you have 10K options. Find a way to narrow those - facets perhaps.

Comment: is there a ready made control that encapsulates this behavior and although its input would be 10k items would not show all of them? anything pre-made? instead of coding from scratch? one that allows moving items from list to anther and back with search that shows only some of items and not all of them on screen? (example input 10k items output show only first 10 when user scrolls more shows 10 more / paging) when moving items again show only the ones required.

Comment: Felix can you post your comment as an answer i want to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ant to have a look at [jQuery UI MultiSelect plugin](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/).

What it does is transform a `html select multiple` into exactly what you want.
I do not know how well it works with very big lists, though. The nice thing is that it will still work if javascript is disabled.

Comment: my main issue is with 10k items and its slow for me also with 10k items.